# How is a character text in a file with ascii encoding stored on disk as file?

Tags: file, memory, encoding, ascii

Let us say I have a 32-bit machine running a 32-bit OS with an application program like Notepad (assume). Assume I create a .txt file with that program which contains just a single character 'A' in it and save the file with ANSI coding (or ASCII) on disk. With 32 bits making up a single addressable memory block called a word, how would the 4 bytes in the word be used to store 'A' (i.e., number 65  in ASCII)? Now, 65 translates to 0100 0001 in binary.

Answer (score 0):

ASCII means, that you are just using one byte per character. many encodings just use one byte per character, but there are some like utf16, which use constantly two bytes for each character.

the 32 bits get just relevant, if your are processing these characters in your CPU in a register, and you load them as an integer. then the single byte is converted to a 32 - bit integer and processed by the cpu, when you save it its again one byte long

how one byte is converted into a 32 bit integer, thats described for example here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness